# Visual Studio, interpret address of variable

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm testing things on a 64-bit system and in Visual Studio I get the following output for this code below..

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int asdf = 32;
    cout << &asdf;
}

00ACF88C
```

In GCC with -m32 I get 0xfffc1828. What are the differences between these two addresses? Is 0xff the same as 00? Are these logical or physical addresses?

Comment: @user4314270: the compiler's free to orchestrate memory for the stack however it likes, so it's entirely unsurprising the addresses didn't match.  It's of no practical consequence.  If you have a use for the address, just take it with `&` and it will be right (i.e. you can dereference it later to refer to `asdf`).  You can trust the compiler to ensure that.  Billy's quip's actually quite a reasonable metaphor for your question.

Comment: No... you see my comment is above that one

Answer (score 1):

The address at which variables are placed is completely up to the implementation. There's nothing special about those addresses other than that's the address your compiler and platform decided to use to store that particular integer at the particular time you ran the program.

On a system with virtual memory most all addresses you can access (unless you're writing the kernel's memory management unit) are going to be virtual addresses.

Comment: Why does the output look different? For example 0xff

Comment: @user: Because different standard library implementations chose to implement the "write a pointer address to the console" function slightly differently.